# How to enter text into an invisible text field

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, android

In my Android, I created my own custom graphics for when the user enter their password.

However, I need to get the numbers keyboard to appear when the user clicks on the password graphic, so I put an `EditText` over the graphic and made it invisible. I was expecting that this would bring up the keyboard when a user tapped on it, but it doesn't. Also, when the user types, I want this text to be added invisibly to the `EditText` and then submitted when complete.

So my question is, how can I create an invisible `EditText` that acts as thought it's not. That is, it brings up the keyboard when tapped and also takes input?

For example, here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/enter_passcode"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/passcode0"
        android:id="@+id/passcodeImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onPasscodeDigitPressed"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try one of these three possibilities for your editText in the xml

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:textcolor="@android:color/transparent"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

or

```
android:alpha="0"
```

or

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Comment: Suggestion #1 worked but I had to add `android:cursorVisible="false"` to complete the effect. You can add that to your answer and I'll accept

Comment: added `android:cursorVisible="false"`. Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/youedittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textcolor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wish I could vote it up but I don't have enough reputation, so please vote me up first :)

Comment: Sometimes people forget.

Answer (score 0):

So, you either way go with: android:textcolor="@android:color/transparent" , or you could do something else like this:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/youedittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

That would make your text like your background ,colour wise, therefor ,you d get "invisible" text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wish I could vote it up but I don't have enough reputation, so please vote me up first :)